Automating database index creations/deletion?
I’m attempting to automate the process of analysing a PostgresQL database using pg_stat_statements to collect the data then automated rust code to analyse and execute the process every (set time).
I havent tested this yet but please provide any feedback or contributions. The goal is to optimise the performance of a pg database as accurate as possible, all automated.
Rust code:
use sqlx::postgres::{PgPool, PgPoolOptions};
use sqlx::{Error, Row};
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};
use tokio::time::{self, Duration};
use log::{info, error};

const INDEX_THRESHOLD_CALLS: i64 = 100; // Minimum calls to consider for index creation
const INDEX_DELETE_THRESHOLD: f64 = 0.2; // Percentage threshold for deleting indexes

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    env_logger::init();

    let pool = PgPoolOptions::new()
        .max_connections(5)
        .connect("postgres://username:password@localhost/dbname")
        .await?;

    schedule_index_management(pool.clone()).await;

    Ok(())
}

async fn schedule_index_management(pool: PgPool) {
    let mut interval = time::interval(Duration::from_secs(24 * 60 * 60)); // 24 hours interval

    loop {
        interval.tick().await;

        info!("Running index management task...");

        if let Err(e) = manage_indexes(&pool).await {
            error!("Failed to manage indexes: {:?}", e);
        }

        info!("Index management task completed.");
    }
}

async fn manage_indexes(pool: &PgPool) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let (indexes_to_create, indexes_to_delete) = analyze_queries(pool).await?;

    create_indexes(pool, indexes_to_create).await?;
    delete_indexes(pool, indexes_to_delete).await?;

    Ok(())
}

async fn analyze_queries(pool: &PgPool) -> Result<(Vec<String>, Vec<String>), Error> {
    let rows = sqlx::query(
        "SELECT query, calls, mean_exec_time 
         FROM pg_stat_statements 
         ORDER BY calls DESC"
    )
    .fetch_all(pool)
    .await?;

    let mut indexes_to_create = Vec::new();
    let mut indexes_to_delete = Vec::new();
    let mut existing_indexes = HashSet::new();
    let mut query_usage = HashMap::new();

    let existing_indexes_rows = sqlx::query("SELECT indexname FROM pg_indexes WHERE schemaname = 'public'")
        .fetch_all(pool)
        .await?;

    for row in existing_indexes_rows {
        let index_name: String = row.get("indexname");
        existing_indexes.insert(index_name);
    }

    for row in rows {
        let query: String = row.get("query");
        let calls: i64 = row.get("calls");

        analyze_query(&query, calls, &mut indexes_to_create, &mut query_usage);
    }

    identify_indexes_to_delete(&query_usage, &existing_indexes, &mut indexes_to_delete);

    Ok((indexes_to_create, indexes_to_delete))
}

fn analyze_query(
    query: &str,
    calls: i64,
    indexes_to_create: &mut Vec<String>,
    query_usage: &mut HashMap<String, i64>,
) {
    if calls >= INDEX_THRESHOLD_CALLS {
        // Example: Implement more sophisticated logic to extract table and column from the query
        if let Some((table, column)) = extract_table_and_column(query) {
            // Example: Determine appropriate index type based on query type and usage pattern
            let index_type = determine_index_type(query);

            let index_name = format!("idx_{}_{}", table, column);
            let index_query = match index_type {
                IndexType::BTree => format!("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS {} ON {} USING btree ({})", index_name, table, column),
                IndexType::Hash => format!("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS {} ON {} USING hash ({})", index_name, table, column),
                IndexType::GiST => format!("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS {} ON {} USING gist ({})", index_name, table, column),
                IndexType::GIN => format!("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS {} ON {} USING gin ({})", index_name, table, column),
                IndexType::BRIN => format!("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS {} ON {} USING brin ({})", index_name, table, column),
            };

            indexes_to_create.push(index_query.clone());
            query_usage.insert(index_name.clone(), calls);
        }
    }
}

fn extract_table_and_column(query: &str) -> Option<(String, String)> {
    // Placeholder logic for extracting table and column from a query
    if query.contains("WHERE") {
        // Example: parsing simple WHERE conditions
        let parts: Vec<&str> = query.split_whitespace().collect();
        if parts.len() > 4 {
            let table = parts[3].to_string();
            let column = parts[5].split('=').next()?.to_string();
            return Some((table, column));
        }
    }
    None
}

enum IndexType {
    BTree,
    Hash,
    GiST,
    GIN,
    BRIN,
}

fn determine_index_type(query: &str) -> IndexType {
    // Example: Implement logic to determine appropriate index type based on query type and usage pattern
    if query.contains("JOIN") {
        IndexType::Hash // Example: Use hash index for joins
    } else if query.contains("WHERE") {
        IndexType::BTree // Example: Use B-tree index for WHERE clauses
    } else {
        IndexType::BTree // Default to B-tree index
    }
}

fn identify_indexes_to_delete(
    query_usage: &HashMap<String, i64>,
    existing_indexes: &HashSet<String>,
    indexes_to_delete: &mut Vec<String>,
) {
    for index in existing_indexes {
        let usage = query_usage.get(index).copied().unwrap_or(0);
        if usage < (INDEX_THRESHOLD_CALLS as f64 * INDEX_DELETE_THRESHOLD) as i64 {
            indexes_to_delete.push(format!("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS {}", index));
        }
    }
}

async fn create_indexes(pool: &PgPool, indexes: Vec<String>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    for index in indexes {
        if let Err(e) = sqlx::query(&index).execute(pool).await {
            error!("Failed to create index: {}", e);
        } else {
            info!("Created index: {}", index);
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

async fn delete_indexes(pool: &PgPool, indexes: Vec<String>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    for index in indexes {
        if let Err(e) = sqlx::query(&index).execute(pool).await {
            error!("Failed to delete index: {}", e);
        } else {
            info!("Deleted index: {}", index);
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}


Many people have tried to automate index creation, but I don't believe that will result in an optimized database.

This just attempts to automate index creation and deletion based on the data from pg_stat_statements extension. The actual analysis logic needs thorough refinement and testing. Ultimately it could be a good starting point then manual corrections can be made? What do you think

Where do you analyze the query plans? And on what statistics do you decide to create a specific index?

Analyze_query function introduces basic logic to decide.
